# How to send an Ajax request using jQuery in Laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, request

I have a heart symbol for the user to select the product I did this with Ajax
I wrote two functions that do this for me, but when we add the product, I have a problem with Ajax to return it.
That is, if I add, I can no longer reduce and we have to refresh the page. After refreshing, I can reduce, but I want to be able to reduce and add without refreshing.
How can I do this?

html :

```
@auth

    <a id="wishlist" href="#"

    class="btn-option btn-option-wishes{{ ($product->checkUserWishlist(auth()->id()))? ' btn-option-favorites remove-wishlist ':' add-wishlist' }}"   data-wishlist="{{ $product->id }}">
        <i class="mdi mdi-heart-outline"></i>
        <span class="tooltip-short">افزودن به علاقه&zwnj;مندی</span>
    </a>

    @else

    <button id="wishlist"  href="#" class="btn-option wishlist-erroe" >
        <i class="mdi mdi-heart-outline"></i>
        <span class="tooltip-short">افزودن به علاقه&zwnj;مندی</span>
    </button>

@endauth
```

js :

```
   $(".remove-wishlist").on('click',function(){
           // event.preventDefault();
           var option_wishes =$(".option-wishes");

            var idProduct = $(this).data('wishlist');

            $.get({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/remove-from-wishlist/'+idProduct,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.growl({
                        title: "توجه",
                        message:data.message ,
                        style:"warning",
                        location:"br",
                        namespace:'growl',
                     });
                        let divWishlist = $("#wishlist");
                        divWishlist.remove();
                        let i = $('<i/>' , {
                            href:'#',
                            class : ' mdi mdi-heart-outline',
                        });
                        let a = $('<a/>' , {
                            id:'wishlist',
                            href:'#',
                            class : 'btn-option btn-option-wishes add-wishlist ',
                            data_wishlist : '{{ $product->id }}',
                        });
                        a.append(i);
                        option_wishes.append(a);

                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.growl({
                        title: "توجه",
                        message: "مشکی رخ داده است ",
                        style:"error",
                        location:"br",
                     });

                }
            });

        });

        $(".add-wishlist").on('click',function(){
           // event.preventDefault();
           var option_wishes =$(".option-wishes");

            var a = $(this).data('wishlist');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', //THIS NEEDS TO BE GET
                url: '/add-to-wishlist/'+a,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.growl({
                        title: "توجه",
                        message:data.message ,
                        style:"notice",
                        location:"br",

                     });
                     let divWishlist = $("#wishlist");
                         divWishlist.remove();
                     let i = $('<i/>' , {
                        href:'#',
                        class : 'mdi mdi-heart-outline',
                    });
                     let a = $('<a/>' , {
                        id:'wishlist',
                        href:'#',
                        class : 'btn-option btn-option-wishes remove-wishlist btn-option-favorites',
                        data_wishlist : '{{ $product->id }}',
                    });
                    a.append(i);
                    option_wishes.append(a);
                },
                error: function() {

                    $.growl({
                        title: "توجه",
                        message: "مشکی رخ داده است ",
                        style:"error",
                        location:"br",
                     });

                }
            });

        });
```

laravel :

```
class WishlistController extends Controller
{
    public function add(Product $product)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {

            Wishlist::create([
                'user_id' => auth()->id(),
                'product_id' => $product->id
            ]);
            return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'محصول مورد نظر به لیست علاقه مندی ها شما اضافه شد'));

        }

    }

    public function remove(Product $product)
    {

        if (auth()->check()) {

            $wishlist = Wishlist::where('product_id', $product->id)->where('user_id', auth()->id())->firstOrFail();

            if ($wishlist) {
             Wishlist::where('product_id', $product->id)->where('user_id', auth()->id())->delete();
               }

            return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'محصول مورد نظر از لیست علاقه مندی ها شما حذف شد'));

        }



    }

    public function usersProfileIndex()
    {
        $wishlist = Wishlist::where('user_id' , auth()->id())->get();
        return view('home.users_profile.wishlist' , compact('wishlist'));
    }
}
```

```
    public function checkUserWishlist($userId)
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Wishlist::class)->where('user_id' , $userId)->exists();
    }
```

Ajax request jQuery Laravel

Hello friends
I have a heart symbol for the user to select the product I did this with Ajax
I wrote two functions that do this for me, but when we add the product, I have a problem with Ajax to return it.
That is, if I add, I can no longer reduce and we have to refresh the page. After refreshing, I can reduce, but I want to be able to reduce and add without refreshing.
How can I do this?

Comment: by reducing  means remove it from ui ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change some lines of js code as follows. From

```
$(".remove-wishlist").on('click',function(){
//code
})
$(".add-wishlist").on('click',function(){
//code
})
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove-wishlist', function () {
//code
})

$(document).on('click', '.add-wishlis', function() {
//code
});
```